# Swift Codable - how to encode and decode stringified JSON values?

Tags: json, swift, codable

The server I'm talking to expects a message in the format:

```
{
  "command": "subscribe",
  "identifier": "{\"channel\": \"UserChannel\"}",
  "data": "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
}
```

Where the `identifier` and `data` values is an escaped json string.

I have this so far:

```
struct ActionCableMessage<Message: Encodable>: Encodable {
    let command: Command
    let identifier: CableChannel
    let data: Message?

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(command, forKey: .command)

        try container.encode(identifier, forKey: .identifier) // ????
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case command, identifier, data
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to do from here. I think I need a `protocol` that `CableChannel` and `Message` can conform to, with a provided `extension` func that implements `encode (to encoder: Encoder)`, which ensures `Encoder` must be a `JSONEncoder`, and if so, uses that to rewrite it's own value as a escaped json string.

I also need to decode this back to the `ActionCableMessage` struct, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I need a protocol that CableChannel and Message can conform to

Well, that protocol is `Encodable` (or `Codable` if you prefer).

```
// just implement these as you normally would
extension CableChannel : Encodable { ... }
extension Message : Encodable { ... }
```

Then in `ActionCableMessage`, you use another encoder to encode the inner objects to JSON data, then convert that to string, then encode that string:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(command, forKey: .command)

    let subencoder = JSONEncoder()
    let identifierString = try String(data: subencoder.encode(identifier), encoding: .utf8)
    
    try container.encode(identifierString, forKey: .identifier)

    // do the same for "data"
}
```

Similarly for decoding:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    command = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .command)
    let identifierJSONString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .identifier)
    // do the same for "data"
    
    let subdecoder = JSONDecoder()
    identifier = try subdecoder.decode(CableChannel.self, from: identifierJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!)
    // do the same for "data"
}
```